# Styled Dropdown not sending correct value onchange on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I'm currently styling my dropdown with [this](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) and using an onchange function:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" tabindex="1" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)"> 
<option selected="true" disabled>Select Quantity</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

But when I view it on the iphone it's passing

```
function updatevariable(data) { 
        var value = data;
             alert(value);
}
```

When I try it on my mac in chrome, it works fine, but on iphone safari it alerts "Select Quantity" as though it hasn't registered the selection properly.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get around this?

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle, jsfiddle.net/DGudM/2 , note it works fine in chrome on mac, but not on iPhone.

Comment: Works good for me on iPhone3S/Safari with this: http://jsfiddle.net/DGudM/ - can you reproduce the problem in the fiddle?

Comment: I think it's a conflict with the script that is styling the dropdown to be honest. Let me see if I can set that in the fiddle.

Comment: @Sergio try this. Just tested on my phone and got the same error. http://jsfiddle.net/DGudM/2/

Comment: Found something interesting... Your plugin uses `.live()` wich is deprecated in older versions of jQuery. Does this work?: http://jsfiddle.net/DGudM/4/

Comment: @Sergio It does! And would you believe, I actually spotted that a few minutes ago and changed it myself, but haven't tested it live on the site yet!
EDIT: Ok, so now i've updated it on the site and it's still not functioning. Have I amended this correctly: `$(document.body).on('change', 'html', function() {
    e.stopPropagation();          
    $("select").selectbox('close'); 
   });`

Comment: Replacing: `$("html").live('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();          
    $("select").selectbox('close'); 
   });` i've updated the source of the plugin now and stil got the same error here http://jsfiddle.net/DGudM/2/

Comment: Ok, it works with jquery 1.8.3 but not 1.9.1 Confused now.

Comment: Latest jQuery that i'm using on the site, along with change in the plugin, returns "NULL" - http://jsfiddle.net/DGudM/5/

Comment: Can you not use the 1.7 or 1.9 version? I tried to find docs for that plugin but site gave me 404

Comment: Yep, I think their site is down currently. Is it not bad practice to use an older jQuery version when working on a new site?

Comment: Yes, find a new better plugin or do the css yourself :)